# How to use adobe CQ i18n in angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, aem

I have created one project in Angular 6, and deployed it in AEM.
Now I want to implement i18 transnational concept using AEM CQ.i18n.
Currently using java script,I create key values in AEM under and folder say En(say for English)and we  created same key values for the translated language(say JA for Japanese).

```
var comboSearch = CQ.I18n.getMessage('comboSearch');


searchContent = searchContent + '<span style="float: left; width: 100%;"><input value="" placeholder="'+comboSearch+'" size=26 style="color:grey;border:#6FA5D7 1px solid;" id="textfield_coursetitle" onKeyPress="if (event.keyCode == 13) {triggerClickEvent(\'callSearch_button\'); return false;}" type="text"></span>';
```

On web page when the user opt to language JA, user shall see the translated value.

Now i need to try the same translation way with Angular 6 in AEM.

Comment: why not you try ngx Translate? any specific reason for CQ i18n ?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/raja-ngx-translate-example ngx translate sample

Comment: What have you tried in Angular?